# Why does JavaScript use a class's super methods over the class's actual methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I'm having a bit of trouble with my JavaScript classes. I have a class called `Client` in a separate file called `Client.js`. I also have `index.js` which invokes that constructor. Inside of the `Client` class, I have a method like the following:

```
setupDatabase(settings) {
    this.db = rethink(settings);
}
```

When I try to use `client.setupDatabase()` inside of the `index.js` file, it explains that `client.setupDatabase is not defined`. I don't really understand this. Someone recently told me that JavaScript prefers to use a class's super methods over the class's actual methods, which I find weird. Here's all of my code: https://h.mayo.pw/nevuniboku.js. Thank you.

Comment: can you paste Client.js ?

Comment: @Noface It's all pasted within the link I sent at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Noface He did in the link at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the way Eris is setup prevents the way that I want to use it. Thanks for everyone that helped out.